# Multiple small requests vs. one big request, Mongo Atlas vs. Mongo docker instance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a stack containing:

- Python fastapi server application
- Mongo database

Currently I am using Mongo atlas for convenience but since I could easily switch to a Mongo DB docker container running on the same cluster/ machine as the server app.

**ISSUE**

I am developing an algorithm that outputs a list of around 50 documents.
The choice of the next document in the list depends on the prior selected documents. Meaning i can not request all 50 documents in a single request to the database but a calculation is necessary after each document.

Currently, for testing reasons, i am simply requesting all documents from the database, around 10.000, and then select in the server app the 50 matching documents. Meaning i have only a single request to the database but a lot of unnecessary documents bloating the cache of the server app, which would in production likely not be scalable.

**IDEA**

Instead of requesting all 10.000 documents from the database, i can call db for each of the 50 documents. This would increase the number of requests from 1 to 50, but the load per call would be reduced to a single document instead of 10.000 documents all at once.
Meaning the load would be shifted from the server app RAM to the number of requests to the database.

**QUESTION**

Considering there could be a couple 100 users interacting with the server app at the same time, from a scalability perspective, which approach would make more sense?

1. like now, requesting all documents at once and putting the burden on the server RAM
2. requesting single documents, which would mean per user request to the server app around 50 consecutive requests for single documents to the Mongo database.
3. if the number of consecutive requests would pose an issue to a Mongo atlas request limit, would it help to switch to a local docker instance of Mongo DB to tackle a possible number of requests per user limit issue and increase the connection speed?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does the calculation/determination of the next document look like?

Comment: It entails multiple calls to other APIs to determine the search criteria for the next document from the mongo db.